# How to flatten tree to table in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I've got a list:

```
List<DataBanerModel> banerData = new List<DataBanerModel>();
banerData.Add(new DataBanerModel { Shop = 1, Cartoon = 1, Box = 1 });
banerData.Add(new DataBanerModel { Shop = 1, Cartoon = 1, Box = 2 });
banerData.Add(new DataBanerModel { Shop = 1, Cartoon = 1, Box = 3 });
banerData.Add(new DataBanerModel { Shop = 1, Cartoon = 2, Box = 1 });
banerData.Add(new DataBanerModel { Shop = 1, Cartoon = 2, Box = 2 });
banerData.Add(new DataBanerModel { Shop = 1, Cartoon = 2, Box = 3 });
banerData.Add(new DataBanerModel { Shop = 1, Cartoon = 3, Box = 1 });
banerData.Add(new DataBanerModel { Shop = 2, Cartoon = 1, Box = 1 });
banerData.Add(new DataBanerModel { Shop = 2, Cartoon = 1, Box = 2 });
banerData.Add(new DataBanerModel { Shop = 2, Cartoon = 1, Box = 3 });
banerData.Add(new DataBanerModel { Shop = 3, Cartoon = 1, Box = 1 });
banerData.Add(new DataBanerModel { Shop = 3, Cartoon = 1, Box = 2 });
banerData.Add(new DataBanerModel { Shop = 3, Cartoon = 1, Box = 3 });
banerData.Add(new DataBanerModel { Shop = 3, Cartoon = 2, Box = 1 });
banerData.Add(new DataBanerModel { Shop = 3, Cartoon = 2, Box = 2 });
```

I have to count how many `Box`es will be in `Cartoon`s and how many `Cartoon`s will be in `Shop`, so the result should be like this:

```
Shop: 1, Cartoons: 3, Boxes: 3
Shop: 1, Cartoons: 3, Boxes: 3
Shop: 1, Cartoons: 3, Boxes: 1
Shop: 2, Cartoons: 1, Boxes: 3
Shop: 3, Cartoons: 2, Boxes: 3
Shop: 3, Cartoons: 2, Boxes: 2
```

So far I wrote:

```
var step4 = banerData.GroupBy(x => x.Shop)
    .Select(s => new
    {
        Shops = s.Key,
        Cartoons = s.GroupBy(y => y.Cartoon)
            .Select(k => new
            {
                k.Key,
                Boxes = k.GroupBy(z => z.Box)
                .Select(p => p.Key).ToList()
            }).ToList()
        }).ToList();
```

and it works fine but I don't know how to flatten this tree.

Comment: This does not look like a Tree Structure, but a basic table. If anything, you are trying to format it *into* a 1:N Relationship - the predecessor of a tree. And the actuall opeation is just grouping with a agregate function like Count, Min, Max. etc. Pretty basic SQL stuff, and one of the first things LINQ copied for SQL: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
  var grouped = banerData
    .GroupBy(d => d.Shop)
    .Select(g => new
    {
      Shop = g.Key,
      Cartoon = g.Select(i => i.Cartoon).Distinct().Count(),
      Box = g
        .GroupBy(i => i.Cartoon)
        .Select(gr => gr.Select(i => i.Box).Distinct().Count())
        .ToArray()
    }).SelectMany(i => i.Box.Select(ii => new { i.Shop, i.Cartoon, Box = ii }))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Hi and Thank you. Unfortunetly, your code result is: 
{ Shop = 1, Cartoon = 3, Box = {int[3]} }
{ Shop = 2, Cartoon = 1, Box = {int[1]} }
{ Shop = 3, Cartoon = 2, Box = {int[2]} }
and it isn't the result I expected

Comment: Now is Ok. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to go a little deep in the expression, following LINQ code will produce the results you wanted in a linear data structure:

```
var step4 = banerData.GroupBy(d => d.Shop).Select(g =>
            new 
            { 
              Shops = g.Key, 
              Cartoons = g.Select(d => d.Cartoon).Distinct().Count(), 
              Boxes = g.GroupBy(d => d.Cartoon).Select(c => c.Select(b=>b.Box).Distinct().Count()) 
            }).SelectMany(d => d.Boxes.Select(b => 
                new 
                { 
                  Shops = d.Shops, 
                  Cartoons = d.Cartoons, 
                  Boxes = b
                })).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

from your expected output, I'm assuming Cartoon value is an id and not number of cartoons in the shop, if this is the case, you'll need to group by Shop and Cartoon together, then get the count.

So you can do this  :

```
var grouped = banerData
    .GroupBy(b => new { b.Shop, b.Cartoon })
    .Select(x => new {
        x.Key.Shop,
        Cartoon = x.Select(e=> e.Cartoon).Count(), 
        Box = x.Select(e => e.Box).Count()
    }).ToList();
```